# Sending and Receiving cXML using Ariba Cloud Integration Gateway

Tags: post, get, sap-ariba, cxml-commercexml

I am about to implement a solution that receives Purchase orders from Ariba and send Invoices to Ariba. the module for handling this in Ariba is called CIG (Cloud Integration Gateway)

When a new PO is created in Ariba it is pushed to my url and when an invoice have been created in our system (SQL) it is pushed to Ariba url.

The application need to be listening for request from Ariba and also be able to listen for new invoices in an SQL database in our system and post them to Ariba.

I am in Visual Studio 2019 and prefer c#, but not really sure what kind of project I should create for handling this kind of operation.

Both the Purchase orders and Invoices are in cXML format using the HTTP protocol.

What would be a good solution/Project for handling this operation?

Comment: I'm working on something similar, also in C#.  What did you come up with?

Comment: I use a httplistener for receiving PO's from Ariba and in the same app I use a timer that looks for new Invoices in SQL and send them to Ariba.